# On click of an ''a'' element, fire it's hover handler instead of going to the link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working with a CMS that doesn't allow me much to do in terms of editing their code.

---

**I have this element:**

```
<a href="/development/tomato_site/" title="SampleTitle"
 class="menu_icon menu-641 sf-depth-1 menuparent" > Tomatos </a>
```

When hovering over this link something pops up which is set through the CMS.

I want on clicking the element, the hover event to happen instead of going to the actual **href link**.

Is this possible to do via jQuery? Maybe dispatch a click event as a hover event?

Comment: Is `hover` set by CSS or js ?

Comment: You can dispatch events and do a lot of other things, but first you'll have to find out what exactly is triggering this pop up, is it CSS, javascript, jQuery etc

Comment: So I cannot just simulate a hover event when clicking on the element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly prevent the default action of clicking and trigger the hover event instead, but **I wouldn't recommend it due to accessibility and usability concerns**.

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).trigger('hover');
});
```

(Here I'm using `a` as the selector but you probably want to be way more specific as to which links you are selecting.)

If the current hovering effect is done via CSS `:hover` pseudo-class, this will not have the desired outcome.

Comment: I am wondering what will happen on an ipad when the user clicks on the element...

Answer (score 2):

jQuery:

```
$( 'whatever selects your link' ).on( 'click', function( ev ){
    ev.preventDefault(); // stop click event
    $( this ).trigger( 'hover' );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below script and trigger `hover` event

```
$( '.menu_icon' ).click(function(){
 $(this).trigger('hover');
 return false;
});
```