# What happens on touch devices when redirecting click events to hover events?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is linked to this question:

[On click of an ''a'' element, fire it's hover handler instead of going to the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25209391/on-click-of-an-a-element-fire-its-hover-handler-instead-of-going-to-the-li/25209509#25209509)

What happens on an iPad when I use this?

```
$( '.menu_icon.menu-641.sf-depth-1.menuparent' ).on( 'click', function( ev ){
    ev.preventDefault(); // stop click event
    $( this ).trigger( 'hover' );
} );
```

I am triggering a hover event when clicking on a hyperlink element.

How does an iPad behave in this scenario? I am aware that touch devices replace hover events with clicks.

Comment: Have you read through this SO question and answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507964/ios-automatic-hover-fix

Comment: A common thing I do with JQuery in general when I want to do something cross platform is add a class attached to some css on touchstart and remove it on touchend. EDIT: touchstart and touchend are the two events.

Comment: The question is what happens in that scenario not how to fix it

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides -- Then try it and see what happens?

Comment: I wouldn't ask this question if I had accessibility to an iPad or any other touch device at this moment.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506708/iphone-ipad-browser-simulator